# DefaultMessageListenerContainer max limit of concurrentConsumers and maxConcurrentConsumers to handle too many messages

Tags: concurrency, parallel-processing, cpu-usage, spring-jms

I want to  concurrently listen the messages(Plenty of messages) from `Queue` using Spring's `DefaultMessageListenerContainer`.

```
<bean id="jmsContainer" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"/>
    <property name="destinationName" ref="queue"/>
    <property name="messageListener" ref="myMessageListener"/>
    <property name ="concurrentConsumers" value ="10"/>
    <property name ="maxConcurrentConsumers" value ="10000"/>        
</bean>
```

I read from the [spring_Forum](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/integration/jms/68926-processing-multiple-queue-messages-simultaneously) that max 5 to 10 concurrentConsumers can be specified in concurrentConsumers and maxConcurrentConsumers.
.

**Question 1 :**

I want to read too many messages as fast as possible.

Can it be possible by increasing the `concurrentConsumers`  & `maxConcurrentConsumers` to **10 thousand** or more than that?

**Question 2:**

Please suggest any other way If it is not efficient way for the too many messages?

Assuming,
`Threads`(Equal to `maxConcurrentConsumers`) running in system is going to start thrashing as it madly context switches between all the running processes (`Threads`).

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22991218/2387977

Answer (score 0):

The optimal number of threads that would process the messages depend on the actual work they are going to do, this is a general topic not directly related to JMS, see for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1718522/1847482).

Possible optimizations related to the JMS itself are first of all connection and session caching. See [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11840630/1847482). Another way is dropping persistence if you can afford this.